# My Dynamic Titles Not Work in Angular on the Server. Dynamic headers do not appear in Source Code (CTRL+U)

Tags: angular, typescript, dynamic, title

I have a angular project. This project's statics titles correctly work but  routing dynamic parameters not change title work. Titles work fine locally but only statics work on server, dynamic titles not updates. Dynamic headers do not appear in Source Code (CTRL+U).

I have a static component, this component correctly work. I am using this package for change title => { Meta, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser'; .

**privacy-component.ts**

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.seoService.updateTitle('Privacy Policy')
  }
```

**My Route Url**

```js
{ path: "gizlilik-politikasi", component:PrivacyPolicyComponent},
```

This component are static. This is correcly work.

**news-detail.ts**

```js
ngOnInit() {
    
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.getNewsById(params["newsId"]);
    });
  }
  getNewsById(newsId) {
    this.newsService.getNewsById(newsId).subscribe(data => {
      this.news = data;
      this.getPhotosByNews(newsId)
      this.seoService.updateTitle(data.title)
    });
  }
```

News Detail Route Url

```js
  { path: "news/:newsId/:title", component: NewsDetailComponent },
```

This component's title change in the local, but not work in Server. This component taking datas in API. I need change dynamic title.